# How can I print a certain line using for line in lines and line length in Python?

Tags: line

I have to use the import sys module for this syntax.  What I have so far is this

```
import sys
file=sys.argv[1]
    fp1= open(file, 'r+')
    fp2= open(file+ 'cl.', 'w+')
    lines =fp1.readlines()
    for line in lines:
     if len(line)>1 and line[0]=='Query':
        print line.split('|') [0:1}
fp1.close()
```

Basically when I run this on the command line:
python homework4.py sqout
It gives me nothing, but if I take away the line[0}=='Query':
it prints the first 2 splits of every line (which I want it to do) just not every line.  I only want it to print the first line which starts with Query.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

line[0] is just the first character of string line. You could use line[0:5]=='Query' or line[:5]=='Query'

Before doing this I suggest checking first that len(line)>4 or using an exception.